# Android - Reference to the fragment used

Tags: android, reference, fragment

Could someone help me? I have 4 fragments that contain some items. I have buttons that are responsible for adding new items and editing. This involves a new class - holder. In this class, so far, I've typed 'add to Fragment number 1'. How can I change this - get a link to the fragment that I'm editing?

I will be grateful for the tips.

EDIT: One of my ideas is to send the value of the class name through the parameter. It works. Anyone have any better idea?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You have running code (an activity?) and you want a reference to a fragment that you've added to the activity?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the `FragmentManager` class documentation, you'll find there a bunch of useful methods to get to the fragments.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Just getting started. I will definitely read what you sent!

Answer (score 1):

To find specific fragment, you could use [findFragmentById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#findFragmentById(int)) or [findFragmentByTag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)).

There are lots of samples about these two methods.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Just getting started. I will definitely read what you sent!